# Can't find custom view in XML palette?

Tags: android, xml, pallet

I can't found custom View tab Android studio palette i search for that but looks like it should be default in palette any help pls , here is image:

[image: Palette screen shot]

Comment: test case: add design dependencie in gradle

Comment: its added already

Comment: Wait what are you finding exactly ? tab layout? custom view? custom view tab?

Comment: i cant find any custom tap at all as shown in my screenshoot

Comment: There is no view such as custom tab in design. what you want to achieve actually any screen shot?